# Set the same height of all divs in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way where i can make ALL my divs have the same height. I have tryed the following:

**HTML:**

```
@foreach (var Image in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-3 test2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a class="img-responsive" href="~/Content/img/@Image.imgUrl" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="My caption">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="ImageThumb" src="~/Content/img/@Image.imgUrl">
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>@Image.Title</h3>
                <p>@Image.imgDesc</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test2').each(function () {
            var highestBox = 0;
            $(this).find('.thumbnail').each(function () {
                if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
                    highestBox = $(this).height();
                }
            })
            $(this).find('.thumbnail').height(highestBox);
        });
    });
```

But this didn't work? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you mean, the highest height should be allotted to all the divs?

Comment: Show us Final generated HTML.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 Yes the Highest height, should be the height of all the thumbnails.

Comment: Try this
 `$(this).find('.thumbnail').css('height', highestBox);`
instead of 
`$(this).find('.thumbnail').height(highestBox);`

Comment: I am not sure if you can do with `.height` of jQuery. I think it only returns the defined height but not the calculated height. So it might be more useful if you try to obtain the height information directly through  `Element.getBoundingClientRect();` or `Window.getComputedStyle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hghtArr = [];
$(".test2 .thumbnail").each(function() {
   hghtArr.push($(this).height());
});
var getMaxHgt = Math.max.apply(Math,hghtArr);
$(".test2 .thumbnail").height(getMaxHgt);
```

Hope this could be helpful, logic is simple.

gather all heights under an array, find the max height, and apply to all.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I dont get why OPs solution which is actually more elegant wouldnt work

Answer (score -2):

No need for javascript here, you might use display:flex (see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

UPDATE:
After Casey note, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="col-sm-3 test2"  style="background:yellow;">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a class="img-responsive" href="~/Content/img/@Image.imgUrl" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="My caption">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="ImageThumb" src="~/Content/img/@Image.imgUrl">
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><br>FOO BAW<br></h3>
                <p><br><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 test2"  style="background:red;">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a class="img-responsive" href="~/Content/img/@Image.imgUrl" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="My caption">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="ImageThumb" src="~/Content/img/@Image.imgUrl">
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>FOO BAW</h3>
                <p>FOO BAW</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Compatibility:
 CSS 3

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/BenoitNgo/nc20f35z/6/

Conclusion:

The idea is to use a flex container on the parent.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11915889)

Comment: @Casey: I updated my answer. Thanks.  
Could people who downgrade me tell why? Else, I can't update my answer.  
Thanks